# Running object property function in a loop

Tags: javascript, function, object, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I am iterating through an object and comparing the property names against a given parameter; if there's a match, I want the property function to be executed. How would I call it other than explicitly?

The object:

```
@headers =
   'foo': (obj)->
       # do stuff
```

The routine:

```
resolve: ('foo', item, obj)->
   for prop of @headers
      if prop == arguments[0]
         # execute obj's foo property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll need to name the 1st argument as CoffeeScript doesn't expect a string to be there.

But, if I understand correctly, you can use the `?` "*existential*" operator (documented in a sub-section of [*Operators and Aliases*](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)) after a [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
resolve: (prop, item, obj)->
   if @headers[prop]?
      obj[prop]()
```

This will compile to:

```
resolve: function(prop, item, obj) {
  if (this.headers[prop] != null) {
    return obj[prop]();
  }
}
```

And, if you want to test for the method on `obj` as well, you can place the `?` between the member operator and arguments/calling parenthesis:

```
obj[prop]?()
```

Comment: The string param is there for clarity. Performance wise, is there any difference between checking if the prop exists and iterating the object? I assume the parser still needs to look through every property and compare in both cases.

Comment: @Metzger Well, for programmer performance, I'd say "*if has prop*" would be a bit more straight-forward than "*for each prop, if equals*." For execution performance, only way to know for certain is to benchmark ([JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/)). But, most engines will likely use something like [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for optimizing single property access over looping.